# Android App Timed Pop Up from Background Service

Tags: android

How can an Android App be set on a timer to popup from the background?

Basically, a countdown is setup within the application, user then clicks HOME button, and then when the timer goes off, it returns the user back to the program.

I found a function moveToBack() but moveToFront or Foreground doesn't work.

This should be exactly like an alarm clock program, but I can't seem to find how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: @user534450: Bear in mind that users get really really angry when things "popup" when they do not feel it is justified. Alarm clocks? Fine. Incoming phone calls? Fine. Just about anything else? Please reconsider, or make it configurable, or something.

Comment: More importantly, consider what happens if your app triggers right as the user is on the phone or playing a game. You need to be sure that this is really what the user wants, at all times.

Answer (score 4):

[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is your friend. You can set it up to start an intent after a certain amount of time.